# Eliminar posiciones vacias de un Arreglo PHP y solo guardar la posicion(aleatoria) que contenga cadena

Tags: php, array

array

```
 0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string 'este comentario se guarda en la base de datos' (length=46)
  3 => string '' (length=0)
  4 => string '' (length=0)
  5 => string '' (length=0)
  6 => string '' (length=0)
  7 => string '' (length=0)
```

dado el array anterior como puedo descartar las posiciones vacías y guardar solamente la posición donde la cadena este llena, para su posterior guardado en una tabla con un campo de tipo comentario

Comment: ¿Cual seria el resultado esperado? Es decir, un arreglo, solo la posición donde esta la cadena? y si hubiese mas posiciones con cadenas?

Comment: hola el resultado esperado seria poder acceder a la pocicion del arreglo donde esta la cadena de texto para poder guardarla en una variable y si solo seria la pocicion donde esta la cadena, en el caso de si hubiese mas variables no es posible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, te interesa recuperar un único valor no vacío del array.

Entonces puedes hacerlo mediante una combinación de `current` con `array_filter`.

Sería simplemente esto, dando por hecho que `$mArray` es el array de valores que presentas:

```
$mValue = current(array_filter($mArray));
echo $mValue;
```

**Salida:**

```
este comentario se guarda en la base de datos
```

Sólo tienes que usar `$mValue` para insertarlo en la base de datos.

*That's all folks!*

Comment: básicamente eso el lo que estaba buscando, algo muy básico, pero para mi que soy muy novato algo desconocido, marque tu respuesta como aceptada porque hace exactamente lo que necesito, muchas gracias amigo.